# Automatically detect the date of the first historical candle of an asset with pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking for a method to automatically detect the date of the first historical candle of an asset. The idea is to use this date with an anchored VWAP. In other words, I want to create an AVWAP that inks itself on the first candle of any chart.

I have no problem with the AVWAP code, I know how to enter a date manually via a menu, or directly in the code, but not how to fetch the date of first historical candle automatically.

Could you please help me? Do you know if it's possible? I've been looking for a while, but unfortunately without success.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executed on each bar starting from the very first bar. So, if you initialize a `var` variable with the time, you will get the time of the first bar. That is because `var` variables will keep their value unless you assign a new value to them.

```
var first_candle_time = time
```

`time` will return the bar time in UNIX format. So, you can use functions like `year()´,` month()` if you want to figure what year/month/day it is.

```
y = year(first_candle_time)
m = month(first_candle_time)
d = dayofmonth(first_candle_time)

if (barstate.islast)
    s = "Year: " + str.tostring(y) + "\n"
    s := s + "Moth: " + str.tostring(m) + "\n"
    s := s + "Day: " + str.tostring(d)

    label.new(bar_index, high, s)
```